# Using google docs as a publishing tool

Tags: firefox, iframe

I am an author of short stories. I like using google docs and I like the idea of when I update a story these changes propagate to the sites I  publish on. This system works fine in the latter versions of chrome and IE. http://plumplucker.com/

This doesn't work in IOS and only when using Opera on android - At present I need to create PDFs to work on an iPhone or an iPad which defeats my purpose of instant updating.

But right now I am trying to get Firefox to display the contents of the embeded iFrames, but FF 9.01 only shows the outline of the iframe containing a blank page. This is btw how ios displays the same page.

Here is my test page http://plumplucker.com/test3.html

In FF this page will load an iframe of my site, but it will not display the stories. I also tried having docs on google apps in case that would act differently - but no difference.

I have tried

Any one have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that I have given up on inserting google doc iframes into my webpages hoping that they will render correctly on all platforms and browsers. That proved to be wishful thinking.

Instead I have constructed an app that builds static pages from the Google doc url's. First I let this happen on the fly every time a user selected a story for viewing, but there was quite a lag with this method and with afterthought I saw no reason not to create static pages. This I do for all my texts even if I have only changed a few details in one of them. I publish PDSs at the same time with TCPDF.